# MarionetteJs extent base controller

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, frontend

Im trying to make a base controller that provides some common functionality that other controller can extend from but somehow Im getting an error when I try to extend my base controller.

Base Controller

```
define(function (require) {
  var Marionette = require('marionette');

  var BaseController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
      // Do stuff
    },

    // Other stuff
  });
  return new BaseController();
});
```

Controller that is extending

```
define(function (require) {
  var Marionette = require('marionette')
    , BaseController = require('controllers/base_controller')
    ;

  var MyController = BaseController.extend({
    // Do stuff
  });

  return new MyController();
});
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function mycontroller.js line 6
```

Maybe I cant extend a controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `new` & `()` from the return statement on the Base controller file

```
return BaseController; // Remove the new && () here
```

Using the `new BaseController()` call is return an `BaseController` instance rather that the constructor function that you are trying to use to `extend` MyController with.

You should also think about removing them from the `MyController` file as well and then make the new instance when you want one;

For Example:

```
// controllers/my_controller.js
define(function (require) {
    var Marionette = require('marionette')
    , BaseController = require('controllers/base_controller');

    var MyController = BaseController.extend({
    // Do stuff
    });

    return MyController;
});

// someotherfile.js
define(function (require) {
   var MyController = require('controllers/my_controller');
   var myControllerInstance = new MyController();
});
```

This way your controller modules will always return the constructor function that you can use to `extend` again rather that returning a single instance:

```
// controllers/my_awesome_controller.js
define(function (require) {
   var MyController = require('controllers/my_controller');
   var MyAwesomeController = new MyController.extend({
       // Extend more awesomeness
   });
   return MyAwesomeController;
});
```